# Migrating Oracle BPEL 10g Process to Apache ODE BPM

Tags: oracle, migration, bpel, apache-ode

I am considering replacing Oracle 10g BPEL Process Manager and migrating all processes to Apache ODE.  Are there documented steps in migrating the processes across the two platforms?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any documentation covering this specific case. However, since BPEL is an industry standard, chances are high that standard compliant parts of your processes can be migrated easily. The problems come with proprietary extensions introduced by vendors. Look for Oracle specific XPath extensions (they typically start with a namespace prefix like `bpelx:`, `ora:` or `oracl:`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12483_01/integrate.1013/b28981/app_xpath_functions.htm) for a list.

The Apache ODE project also maintains a [list of extensions](http://ode.apache.org/bpel-extensions.html), so perhaps you can find an equivalent replacement there. Another helpful resource explains ODE's [compliance to BPEL](http://ode.apache.org/ws-bpel-20-specification-compliance.html).